# Вызвать js сообщение по условию

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть файл JS, в котором передаётся `id` продукта в обработчик PHP. Сам обработчик возвращает или '`success`' или '`error`'. 
Когда с обработчика возвращает '`error`' окно(`swal`) об ошибке выводится, но если обработчик возвращает '`success`', в условие `(if(response == 'success'))` заходит, но окно не выводит.

```js
function AjaxAddInCart(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://practice//CHeckSessionAndAddProductInCart',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'IDProduct=' + id,
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == 'error') {
        swal({
          title: 'Для добавления в корзину требуется войти в аккаунт!',
          icon: 'error',
          button: 'OK'
        });
      } else {
        if (response == 'succes') {
          swal({
            title: 'Товар добавлен в корзину',
            icon: 'success',
            button: 'OK'
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите код не картинкой, а сниппетом.

Comment: У вас на скрине сравнение со строкой `succes` вместо `success`  - это так задумано?

Comment: Да, я с синтаксисом ошибся немного, но это не суть важно, так как обработчик отправляет 'succes'. Именно то, что прописано в условии в коде js. Я Debug прошёлся, в условие 'succes' заходит, но окно не показывает.
После if(response == 'succes') ставил обычный Alert и он выполняется.
Не выполняется именно swal. Если убираю условие, которое обрабатывает 'error', тогда 'succes' выполнится.

Comment: Получилось.
Вопрос закрыт.